# Jquery: can't fire handlers with live

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have

```
$('#launcher').live('click',function(){
    Results()
    Count()
})
```

But when i try to add a third function it breaks:

```
$('#launcher').live('click',function(){
    Results()
    Count()
    thirdDontWork()
})
```

and the third isn't fired, same if i was to have it like so:

```
$('#launcher').live('click',Count, Results)
```

I have about 6 handlers i need attached

EDIT:
This works fine so the functions all work

```
     $('#launcher').live('click', Results)
 $('#launcher').live('click', Count)
 $('#launcher').live('click', thirdDontWork) //it actual works here...
```

Comment: The problem is with your third function, and not with jQuery or `.live`.

Comment: have you checked in firebug for a javascript error in `THirdDOntWOrk`?

Comment: There error should be in this function: `THirdDOntWOrk()`

Comment: Not sure what you doing but the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handler see link: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @delboud Post the whole problem area code. Maybe we will be able to help you.

Comment: If i made another event handler under this one and fired the function it works fine.

Comment: @delboud Definitely chalk that one up to not putting in commas. ;)

Comment: @delboud Wait... Is it because you had the variable spelled wrong?  (I see it is no longer spelled `THirdDOntWOrk` like it was in the original post.)

Comment: No, it was a typo the first time before i edited

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure the issue is that `THirdDOntWOrk` is not defined within the scope of the context you are trying to call it from.  Please post the full code.

A few things:

- As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.
- You should not skip the ending commas, as this can "sometimes" cause weird issues - like breaking crazily-named-standard-less function names.

If you post more details we can help you figure out the problem.  It's really hard to **guess** what your other code is doing/not-doing.

Comment: Not able to upgrade to 1.7 as of now